# How to disable event propagation to lower level layers?

Tags: coco2d-x

I use cocos2d-x 3.0 RC1 and I need the following: the topmost layer should get all the events, and should not propagate the events to the layers that are below the topmost layer. I don't know how I can do that. I have tried to figure out something with `setTouchEnabled` and `setSwallowTouches` but null result.

Please help. this is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I have found is to implement this:

```
auto m_touchListenerOneByOne = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
m_touchListenerOneByOne->setSwallowTouches(true);
m_touchListenerOneByOne->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(IntroView::onBoardTouchBegan, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(m_touchListenerOneByOne, this);
```

the code above I wrote in init method of the layer. Also this:

```
bool IntroView::onBoardTouchBegan(Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    CCLOG("AAAAAAAAA!");
    return true;
};
```

When you return true in `onBoardTouchBegan` you “consume” touch, otherwise if layer don’t consume touches those touches are passed to next Layer by priority.